# Coloring table or dataframe rows or columns in R

Tags: r, colors, row, dataframe, highlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R gvisTable pre-selection using event trigger option and javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321883/r-gvistable-pre-selection-using-event-trigger-option-and-javascript-code)

Hi I have a table/dataframe/xts/matrix object, and would like to be be able to highlight specific rows and columns in different colors ...I think I saw this before, but can't find it anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Any pretty knitr outputs would also be nice if thats possible...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310971/colorize-highlight-values-of-r-ftable-output-in-knitr-sweave-rapports

Comment: What's the target document? HTML, LaTeX, spreadsheet?

Comment: I think gvisTable might have something there but cant quite work out the option to setSelection to a specific row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-asked this question focusing in on a gvisTable getting an HTML output and got a fairly good answer from Jeff Allen.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321883/r-gvistable-pre-selection-using-event-trigger-option-and-javascript-code) to the other question if anybody is interested...